# What's the best(free) vnc server software

Tags: remote-desktop, iphone, vnc, vncserver

I want a good VNC server to connect to my PC from my iPhone. What's my best bet?

Comment: Should be a wiki.

Comment: another good option now , not a VNC server, is chrome remote desktop!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ultra VNC](http://www.uvnc.com/download/)!

Also good:
[Tight VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/)
[Real VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/download.html)

Comment: Tight VNC is a good version.

Comment: There is a few iPhone VNC Clients available. The OP asked for a server .

Comment: I saw that after I reread the question ;o)

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) as the server.  Any of the aforementioned VNC clients on the iPhone can connect to it.