# which one should you recommend for a free vnc client under windows

Tags: vnc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Performing Remote Desktop solution (for LAN)](https://superuser.com/questions/101453/best-performing-remote-desktop-solution-for-lan)

I'll shift from putty to vnc，not because putty is bad , just baecause that I need to keep the session up dan running for some testing task. So I'm looking for a free vnc client which might as good as putty from user exerience point will . what will be your choice ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/101453/best-performing-remote-desktop-solution-for-lan http://superuser.com/questions/15357/whats-the-bestfree-vnc-server-software

Comment: @HaiYuan: also consider running *GNU screen* inside your PuTTY window.  if the PuTTY connection gets cut off, you can reconnect to the screen session later.  basic tutorials: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/34 ... http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935

Answer (score 1):

Which OS are you running?

I've always used Ultra VNC, both in Linux and Windows environments, its free and has always been ultra reliable and very robust.

Find it at: http://www.uvnc.com/