# Remotely execute app but then redirect the gui output Windows

Tags: remote-access

Similar to X server where the app can run on a remote pc then the output (just the applications gui) would redirected to the client but on Windows not Linux. Is this possible with XP? I only have an XP install cd that I don't use any more.

Answer (score 2):

VNC will give you essentially remote access to your machine and execute everything remotely.  It is not on a per app basis like X is, but should give you similar results.

Check out this question for the software: [What's the best(free) vnc server software](https://superuser.com/q/15357/820)

Comment: Without having a Citrix or Windows Server 2008 machine, VNC is probably going to be your best bet. UltraVNC (possibly other clients as well) allow you to display just a single window rather than viewing an entire desktop. However, you'll still be interacting with the console session so you're realistically limited to one user at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Windows itself wasn't designed for this. The only thing I know of that comes close to what you describe is Citrix. But it's expensive, and not exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

RDP works similar to this, but you'll get a complete new user-session. All processing will be done on the server, the GUI gets drawn on the client, AFAIK.